# Capturing substrings if followed by certain string

Tags: regex, recursion, capture

I'm trying to capture the name of the message that are between quotes. It can be formatted like

> `("AddMessage",function(e){...})`

or i.e.

> `("AddMessage","RemoveMessage",function(e){...})`

I'm trying to capture the name of the messages with a regex but, on the regex I tried

```
\("(?<name>\w+Message)"(,"(\w+Message)")*,function\([\w,]*\){.*?}\)
```

[Regex101 tells me](https://regex101.com/r/QQXDzc/2) to make a group recursive to capture multiples message's name.

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data.

I really can't get it, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/QQXDzc/3), this is one of the ways.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This one works aswell, but I need to be sure that the word "function" at the end is present orelse, it can match something I don't want
i.e.
("AddMessage",{test:test})

Comment: The regular expression you posted on regex101 does not match the question you are asking here. And it will help if you can be more clear on what you are asking.

Comment: Will not be easy, English is not my birth language.
I'm trying to capture the name of the message that are between quotes.
It can be formatted multiple way
i.e.
("AddMessage",function(e){...}) or ("AddMessage","RemoveMessage",function(e){...})
I'm trying to capture the name of the messages with a regex but, on the regex I posted, regex101 tell me to make a group recursive to capture multiples message's name.

Comment: You can [use a lookahead](https://www.regex101.com/r/mH1Tl7/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to capture the repeated sections into an enclosing capture group.

Add a named capture group *around* the repeated sections, and use "grouping only" (no capture group is captured) for the inner:

```
\("(?<name>\w+Message)",?(?<messages>(?:"\w+Message",?)*),function\([\w,]*\){.*?}\)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/fFLWY8/1)

Comment: OMG ! It's exactly what I needed, I'll thank you so much !